# dts channel mixer macos

Tags: macos, audio, vlc-media-player, 5.1

In all DTS based files i play, i have the classical problem of voice volume being too low and explosions too loud. I do not like to " ride the volume ".

Hardware is :

```
- Audigy 2zs pci card + kx drivers
- Mac Os 10.10
- Pioneer VSX-918v receiver ( 5.1 / stereo used )
- Floor stander speakers ( stereo system / only 2 speakers )
- connection is done via standard analog stereo output
- software used ( at the moment ) VLC Media Player.
```

I know that on a windows based system i can ( could ) use FFDshow to raise the center channel ( where the voice is located on a dts track ). Also on Windows i can output digital over coaxial cable to the receiver and for dts-in it has a volume matrix, where i can lower ( or raise ) the channel volume independently.

The only solution i`ve found is using the compressor in VLC. This generates a very bad sound.

Also i can enable a few compression modes on the receiver : Midnight, AutoVolumeLeveling, Voice mode on the equaliser. All of these modify the rest of the sound also.

What i need is a way ( or a software player ) to raise the center channel volume. Like a  volume matrix ( old AC3 Filter on windows / dts matrix in FFDShow ). Is there such a solution for macos ?

Comment: This does not answer the question but it provides a fix : Output audio via hdmi cable to the tv, the tv then outputs via optical cable to the receiver. This way i can send digital signal to the receiver. Receiver "knows" to raise the volume of the voices using a setting called " Dialog mode".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 5.1 on my Mac [I have a dedicated PC I use for movies], so this is a bit of a guess...
Apps > Utilities > Audio Midi Setup. Should be able to adjust individual channel volumes in there.

This is how my stereo output looks. Also check in 'Configure Speakers...' that it's set up for 5.1

[image]

*Edit* - I just realised you said only 2 speakers... not sure how that's going to work, unless you're pre-mixing at the Mac as 5.1 then muxing back to stereo in your amp.

Comment: The movie is 5.1 DTS, it gets downmixed in the player ( software ) and then sent to the receiver as 2.0 . What i am trying to control is the downmixing done via software .